# Rename strings in Android

Tags: java, android, localization

I'd like to rename the keys of my strings.xml file.

Is possible to do it with eclipse automatically updating the references in the code and xml files?

Thanks

Comment: what you want to do??do you want to change the string.xml code?

Comment: alt+shift+R will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes man Just follow the steps and do a trick

1) Select the key that you want to update

[image]

2) Press Alt + Shift +R

[image]

3) Change to new name and update.

Answer (score 2):

Put pointer on resourse and press Alt + Shift + R